# Can I force Gmail's Chrome Custom Tab to handle a deeplink

Tags: android, gmail, deep-linking, android-7.0-nougat

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity android:name=".MyUrlDeepLinkActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="my.site.com" />
        <data android:pathPattern="/whatever" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`bit.ly/2htafii` redirects to `my.site.com/whatever`.

Gmail on a Nougat device redirects `bit.ly/2htafii` to `my.site.com/whatever` within a Chrome Custom Tab, but doesn't register as a deeplink.

Is there a way to ensure that the deeplink will get picked up after a redirect from within Gmail, without requiring the user to turn off "Open web links in Gmail"?

Comment: I strongly recommend you read **[how to create Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** and edit your question accordingly before it gets downvoted and burried.

Comment: To make sure I understand what you're telling me: you feel that there should be more sample code?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm opening a Custom Tab which redirects to what should be a deep link (and behaves as this way in normal Chrome) but it doesn't launch a 3rd party app

Comment: I didn't I'm afraid :(